# Include only one property of nested object to toString method using Lombok

Tags: java, tostring, lombok

i have a following case:

```
@Data
public class Human{
   private long id;
   private Pet pet;
   //other properties...
}
```

```
@Data
public class Pet{
   private long id;
   private Human owner;
   //other properties...
}
```

I use lombok dependency and when `toString` is used, application throws `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. I know I can use `@ToString.Exclude` to exclude given field, but in such case i would like to have only a nested object's `id` proeprty to be shown in a `toString` method.
In other words, if an object's `toString` calls it's nested property `toString`, then (and only then) I want to see only that object `id`. But if i call that's object `toString` not from a parent object, I want to see a regular `toString`. 
I know that i can define `toString`, `equals` and `hashCode` methods by myself this way, but is this possible to tell lombok to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to add a getter for the pet/owner IDs, and mark that as `@ToString.Include`:

```
@Data
class Human{
    private long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Pet pet;

    @ToString.Include
    public long petId() { return pet.getId(); }

    //other properties...
}

@Data
class Pet{
    private long id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Human owner;

    @ToString.Include
    public long ownerId() { return owner.getId(); }
}
```

Usage:

```
var human = new Human();
var pet = new Pet();
human.setPet(pet);
pet.setOwner(human);
System.out.println(human);

// Output:
// Human(id=0, petId=0)
```

Note that you might also want to mark `pet` and `owner` as `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`, because otherwise `equals` and `hashCode` might also cause stack overflows in some situations.